# Probability Set Theory

Tags: probability

If P(A $\cap$ B) = P(A) = P(B), does this imply that P(A$^c$ $\cap$ B) = $0$? Prove or provide a counterexample.

My intuition tells me that the above statement implies that A = B in which case the assertion would be true, though I am having a hard time formalizing this.

Comment: Hint: $ \{A\cap B, A^c \cap B\}$ is a partition of $B$

Answer (score 0):

It actually suffices to know that $\mathbb{P}(B) = \mathbb{P}(A\cap B)$. Indeed, since $A\cap B$ and $A^{c}\cap B$ are disjoint and their union gives $B$, additivity of $\mathbb{P}$ implies $$\mathbb{P}(B) = \mathbb{P}(A\cap B) + \mathbb{P}(A^{c}\cap B) = \mathbb{P} (B) + \mathbb{P}(A^{c}\cap B),$$ where we have used the assumption in the second step. This immediately gives $\mathbb{P}(A^{c}\cap B) = 0$.

It is, however, not true in general that $A = B$. Consider, for example, for $\mathbb{P}$ the probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$ with all its mass concentrated at $0$ (the Dirac measure $\delta_0$) and $A = [1,3]$, $B=[2,4]$.

Comment: In other words:  $\mathbb P(A^{\small\complement}\cap B)=0$ does *not* mean that  $A^{\small\complement}\cap B$ is empty, only that the event is a null set.